# Aggregating data to get a running total month on month

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table which holds the below data

[image: just a snippet of the data in the table]

This issue im having is that i need a running total for each month, I've managed to create this is an excel sheet pretty easily but when i try anything in SQL the data result varies.

The image below shows the sum of each paid amount by month, then a total of each one added onto it. I've edited excel to show the formula and the result of the formula. Also have the result i get from SQL 2008 when using  (example only)

***UPDATE - The result set im trying to achieve that is in the excel document is for example month 117 + Month 118 gives Month118 TotalToDate, then month 118 + 119 gives Months 119 Total to Date.

Not sure how else to explain this?

> ( select sum(paid) from #tmp005 t2 where t2.[monthid] <=
>   t5.[monthid] ) as paid

[image]

Really feel that this is less complicated than what I think!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand this you are trying to get a running total month by month, the below CTE should do what you want.

```
--create table #temp (M_ID Int, Paid Float)

--Insert Into #temp VALUES (116, '50.00'), (117, '50.00'),(117, '5.00'),(117, '20.00'),(117, '10.00'),(117, '75.40'),(118, '125.00'),(118, '200.00'),(118, '5.00')

;WITH y AS 
(
  SELECT M_ID, paid, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY M_ID)
    FROM #temp
), x AS
(
    SELECT M_ID, rn, paid, rt = paid
      FROM y
      WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT y.M_ID, y.rn, y.paid, x.rt + y.paid
      FROM x INNER JOIN y
      ON y.rn = x.rn + 1
)
SELECT M_ID, MAX(rt) as RunningTotal 
    FROM x
    Group By M_ID  
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000);
```

It is based on the first 3 M_ID of your sample data, just change around the #temp to your specific table, I didn't know whether you had another unique identifier in the table which is why I had to use the `ROW_NUMBER()`but this should order it correctly based on the M_ID field.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are storing the month in a separated table and using `M_ID` to reference it. So, to get the sum of each month do this:

```
SELECT [M_ID]
       ,sum([Paid]) 
FROM #tmp005
GROUP BY [M_ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd use a correlated sub query:-

```
select r.m_id,
(
    select sum(csq.paid)
    from #tmp005 csq
    where csq.m_id<=r.m_id
)
from (
    select distinct m_id
    from #tmp005
) r
```

Hopefully you can figure out how to apply it to your circumstance/schema.